# How can I call a method written in class1 to class2?

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have class1.m . I declared a method and written in it. Now i need to call it into another class. How can I make it? Can we use extern for it like we use for variables.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate your declaration and definition, and place the declaration for class1 in class1.h. Then, you should include class1.h using `#import "class1.h"` in your source file for class2. Within class2, you can instantiate and use class1 as follows:

```
class1* instance_of_class1 = [[class1 alloc] init];
[class1 invokeMyMethod];
```

When you are done using your instance, be sure to decrement the reference count via release as in:

```
[instance_of_class1 release];
instance_of_class1 = nil;
```

Comment: Thank You.

I had a method (method1) in in Class1. I declared it in Class1.h and implemented in Class1.m. I have Class2 and it have a selector:@selector(method1). In this case how can I do it ?

Comment: It is more efficient to simply call the method directly using [instance method1]. However, if you need to use dynamic typing and invoke the selector in that way, you can use the "performSelector" method which is defined in NSObject (which should be a base class, either directly, or indirectly of your class).

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading Apple's [Objective-C Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) which will cover the fundamentals you need to know.